# How to delete unwanted lines in an array

Tags: xamarin.android

I use the following method by OCR to transfer the written values ​​to the array.
The problem I have is I want to ignore any line containing a word or letters less than 13 length.

```cs
SparseArray items = detections.DetectedItems;
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < items.Size(); ++i)
{
    istring s = ((TextBlock)items.ValueAt(i)).Value;
    int length = S.Length;
    if (length > 13)
    {
        strBuilder.Append(result);
        strBuilder.Append("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can remove the line by `items.Remove(i);` if `length > 13`. Is this you want?

Comment: I added an answer and can you please mark the answer so that we can help more people with same problem")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the line by `items.Remove(i);` if `length > 13`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.Size(); ++i)
{
    istring s = ((TextBlock)items.ValueAt(i)).Value;
    int length = S.Length;
    if (length > 13)
    {
        items.Remove(i);

        strBuilder.Append(result);
        strBuilder.Append("\n");
    }
}
```